# App Engine Endpoints library - NoClassDefFound for both my Api and its $Builder

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven

I'm stuck with the connection to my api built on the App Engine Endpoints platform. After I attach the generated library to my Android Client, use it and build an application it always says that either my Api or Api$Builder was not found (at runtime). It is clearly visible and accessible while developing the code or at compile time.

I've tried two different approaches:
- attaching the .jar generated by maven appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib goal
- attaching the sources of these classes generated by the same goal

Both of the approaches make the classes visible and usable still at runtime there's an exception NoClassDefFound (when I actually call it) and an error that the class could not be found by dalvikvm.

I have the referenced library in Order/Export tab selected. Although it is at the latest position (tried with any other). I have also checked the Android 5.0 lib as well as Android Private Libraries (got Android Dependencies and Maven Dependencies unchecked - did not work with Maven's checked aswell).

It is a worth mentioning that the moment I created the test projects in Eclipse with GAE plugin (with no maven) it worked perfectly. I cannot figure out where the problem is.

I can provide with any information you'd like to have to get this problem solved. Just ask in comments so I update with the required information.

A part of my code in MainActivity of the Android application:

```
protected TestUser callApi() throws IOException
{
    Api.Builder api = new Api.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new       AndroidJsonFactory(), null);
    return api.build().hello("ANY").execute();
}
```

My API code:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;
import com.test.user.Contact;
import com.test.user.TestUser;
import com.test.user.status.Status;
import com.test.utils.Utils;

/** An endpoint class we are exposing */
@Api(
    name = "api", 
    version = "v1", 
    description = "My Own Api",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "com.test.server", 
            ownerName = "com.test.server", 
            packagePath = ""),
    scopes = { Utils.EMAIL_SCOPE }
)
public class ApiService
{
    /**
     * Api Method for Testing purposes.
     * 
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "hello")
    public TestUser hello(@Named("name") String name)
    {
        TestUser response = new TestUser();
        response.setId(123);
        response.setName(name);

        return response;
    }
}
```

POM of my Android project:

```
<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <appengine.app.version>2</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.14</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>21</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

POM of my API app:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>google-staging</id>
        <name>Google Staging</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.14</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <port>8888</port>
                <address>0.0.0.0</address>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT 14:43 1.11.2014:

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.client"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons" />
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that a required jar was not found on the server. You don't see an error in Eclipse because you did add all the required jars to your class path.

In Eclipse, select your project and click on the Problems tab. See if there are any warnings saying "... will not be available on the server...". Right click on this warning and select "Copy" option.

Note that another possibility is that you have more than one copy of the required jar in that folder, in which case you should delete all copies, add the right jar, and clean the project.